# AVAudioPlayer to AVCaptureSession

Tags: avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avcapturesession

I would like to help in this regard. 
In practice, during a AVCaptureSession I wish the audio was captured by a provieniente AVAudioPlayer that plays an mp3.

I try to explain better with a drawing

[my idea in a simple drawing](http://i58.tinypic.com/w6y5oo.jpg)

follows the code that I currently use, but unfortunately that does not comply with my request ...

```
**//ADD DEVICE AUDIO INPUT
//NSLog(@"Adding audio input");
AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];
    if (audioInput)
    {
        [CaptureSession addInput:audioInput];
    }**
```

Thank you everyone for your attention, greetings;-)